# what is the check duplicate classes error?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-notification, awesome-notifications

I just added the lib awesome_notifications_fcm and when compiling it for android getting this error, havent even implemented yet.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.AwesomeNotifications found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.AwesomeNotifications$1 found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.AwesomeNotificationsExtension found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.BuildConfig found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.Definitions found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.Definitions$1 found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.background.BackgroundExecutor found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.broadcasters.receivers.AwesomeBroadcastReceiver found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.broadcasters.receivers.AwesomeEventsReceiver found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.broadcasters.receivers.AwesomeExceptionReceiver found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.broadcasters.receivers.DismissedNotificationReceiver found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.broadcasters.receivers.NotificationActionReceiver found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.broadcasters.receivers.NotificationActionReceiver$1 found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.broadcasters.receivers.RefreshSchedulesReceiver found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.broadcasters.receivers.ScheduledNotificationReceiver found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.broadcasters.senders.BroadcastSender found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.builders.NotificationBuilder found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.builders.NotificationBuilder$1 found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.completion_handlers.ActivityCompletionHandler found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.completion_handlers.BitmapCompletionHandler found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.completion_handlers.NotificationThreadCompletionHandler found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.completion_handlers.PermissionCompletionHandler found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.decoders.BitmapResourceDecoder found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.enumerators.ActionType found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.enumerators.DefaultRingtoneType found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.enumerators.ForegroundServiceType found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.enumerators.ForegroundServiceType$1 found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.enumerators.ForegroundStartMode found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.enumerators.ForegroundStartMode$1 found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.enumerators.GroupAlertBehaviour found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.enumerators.GroupSort found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.enumerators.LogLevel found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.enumerators.MediaSource found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.enumerators.NotificationCategory found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.enumerators.NotificationImportance found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.enumerators.NotificationImportance$1 found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)


     Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 18s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

My build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle file at app level

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.superwizor"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 29
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}



configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        if (details.requested.name == 'firebase-iid') {
            details.useVersion('21.1.0')
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'
    
}
```

my gradle.properties file

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

my pubspec.yaml file

```
name: example
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.15.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: 'flutter'
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.5
  scrollable_positioned_list_extended: ^0.3.8
  flutter_chatbook:
    path: ../
  # giphy_message:
  #   path: ../packages/giphy_message/  
  uuid: ^3.0.7
  scroll_to_index: ^3.0.1
  moxxmpp:
    hosted: https://git.polynom.me/api/packages/Moxxy/pub
    version: 0.2.0
  moxxmpp_socket_tcp:
    hosted: https://git.polynom.me/api/packages/Moxxy/pub
    version: 0.2.1
  sticky_grouped_list:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/Yogesh-Dubey-Ayesavi/sticky_grouped_list.git  
  get_it: ^7.4.1
  supabase_flutter: ^1.10.3
  rxdart: ^0.27.7
  material_theme_builder: ^1.0.4
  dynamic_color: ^1.6.5
  google_fonts: ^5.1.0
  awesome_notifications:^0.7.4+1
  awesome_notifications_fcm: ^0.7.4+1
  device_info_plus: ^9.0.2


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: 'flutter'
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.1

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

its saying that duplicate classes are being found but i dont know how can i remove them any help would be highly appreciated, i even tried solving conflicts but nothing worked ?

Comment: it seems like that `awesome_notifications ` conflicted with `awesome_notifications_fcm `, try to remove one and rebuild

Comment: well see here https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications_fcm#plugin-dependencies they have mentioned to use both of the libs together in order to make it work, awesome_notifications_fcm is built on top of awesome_notifications

Comment: Bro try to check grandle dependancies. you may added duplicate dependency for it

Comment: @AkashKashyap Hey bro, im getting the same error now. did you fix it?